# Splitting E2C Source Email Addresses

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, custom-field, string, email2case

I am currently trying to set a flow variable based on ToAddress value that comes in via an E2C situation. I realized that there are multiple email addresses being stored in that text field. Sometimes it will come in with 1 adress....sometimes 5 that are all separated by colon. Is there a way to split one particular address from the group in the text field if it consistently starts with the same two letters via a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to `EmailMessage.ToAddress` field - then because this is a text area long field (length 4000), you will not be able to use formula expressions.

You will need to either:

- If doing this in a before insert/update context - use an Apex trigger
- If doing this in an after insert/save or screen flow context, use an invocable Apex action.

The Apex String class has a handy `split` method that can split a string into an array based on a delimiter